# Update span on mouseup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, select

I have span and select in my view

Here is code of it

```
<li>
  <select name="search[adults]" id="search_adults" class="custom" style="display: none;">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1 vuxen</option>
    <option value="2">2 vuxna</option>
    <option value="3">3 vuxna</option>
    <option value="4">4 vuxna</option>
    <option value="5">5 vuxna</option>
    <option value="6">6 vuxna</option>
    <option value="7">7 vuxna</option>
    <option value="8">8 vuxna</option>
    <option value="9">9 vuxna</option>
  </select>
  <span tabindex="0" id="search_adults-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="search_adults-menu" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-button ui-widget ui-selectmenu-button-open ui-corner-top" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">1 vuxen</span>
  </span>
</li>
```

I need to open selectmenu on `mousedown` event and get value of an element on `mouseup` when I move my mouse into select.

For mousedown I wrote code and it works great

```
$("#search_adults-button").on("mousedown", function() {
  $("#search_adults").selectmenu("open");
});
$('#search_adults-button').on("click", function() {
  $("#search_adults").selectmenu("open");
});
```

But I cannot understand how to handle `mouseup`

Here is screen of select with span.

[image: screen]

For example I click span holding the mouse and then I move it to 2 vuxna and release it. And I would like to get 2 vuxna.

I tried to do it like this

```
$("#search_adults-button").on("mouseup", function() {
  var conceptName = $('#search_adults').find(":selected").text();
  alert(conceptName);
});
```

But it does not work. Because `mouseup` event works only when mouse in span and gets 1 vuxna.

Here is snippet to show problem

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#speed" ).selectmenu();
    $("#speed-button").on("mousedown", function() {
  $("#speed").selectmenu("open");
});
$('#speed-button').on("click", function() {
  $("#speed").selectmenu("open");
});
$("#speed-button").on("mouseup", function() {
  var conceptName = $('#speed').find(":selected").text();
  alert(conceptName);
});
    
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="demo">
 
<form action="#">
 
  <fieldset>
    
    <select name="speed" id="speed">
     <option selected="selected" value="1">1 vuxen</option>
    <option value="2">2 vuxna</option>
    <option value="3">3 vuxna</option>
    <option value="4">4 vuxna</option>
    <option value="5">5 vuxna</option>
    <option value="6">6 vuxna</option>
    <option value="7">7 vuxna</option>
    <option value="8">8 vuxna</option>
    <option value="9">9 vuxna</option>
    </select>
 
   
  </fieldset>
 
</form>
 
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

How I can handle my problem?

Comment: Please give your html and javascript so that it would possible to reproduce the problem. With the code that you given it is impossible for me to help you.

Comment: I give you html and js @KrzysztofJaniszewski

Comment: Can you read? With the code that you given it is impossible for me to help you. What you gave is not enough. Please raed and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can read . Here is fiddle. Not same id's, But same functionality -https://jsfiddle.net/nemesises666/4srhxo4d/1/ @KrzysztofJaniszewski

Comment: And I added snippet here @KrzysztofJaniszewski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, great. With the code you gave I was able to reproduce your problem and come to a solution.

Problem was, that on `mouseup` you did not update select value.

**Here is a working example** (I hope this is what you wanted)

```js
$(function() {
var select = $('#speed');
  select.selectmenu();

  $("#speed-button").on("mousedown", function() {
    select.selectmenu("open");
  });
  $('#speed-button').on("click", function() {
    select.selectmenu("open");
  });

  $(document).on("mouseup", ".ui-menu-item-wrapper", function() {
    select.val($(this).text().substr(0, 1)).change();
    select.selectmenu("close");
    select.selectmenu("refresh");
  });

});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="demo">
  <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
      <select name="speed" id="speed">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1 vuxen</option>
        <option value="2">2 vuxna</option>
        <option value="3">3 vuxna</option>
        <option value="4">4 vuxna</option>
        <option value="5">5 vuxna</option>
        <option value="6">6 vuxna</option>
        <option value="7">7 vuxna</option>
        <option value="8">8 vuxna</option>
        <option value="9">9 vuxna</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

**Here is an example with two select fields**

```js
$(function() {
  var selectSpeed = $('#speed'),
    selectTest = $('#test');

  selectSpeed.selectmenu();
  selectTest.selectmenu();

  $("#speed-button").on("mousedown", function() {
    selectSpeed.selectmenu("open");
  });
  $('#speed-button').on("click", function() {
    selectSpeed.selectmenu("open");
  });

  $(document).on("mouseup", "#speed-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper", function() {
    selectSpeed.val($(this).text().substr(0, 1)).change();
    selectSpeed.selectmenu("close");
    selectSpeed.selectmenu("refresh");
  });

  
  $("#test-button").on("mousedown", function() {
    selectTest.selectmenu("open");
  });
  $('#test-button').on("click", function() {
    selectTest.selectmenu("open");
  });

  $(document).on("mouseup", "#test-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper", function() {
    selectTest.val($(this).text().substr(0, 1)).change();
    selectTest.selectmenu("close");
    selectTest.selectmenu("refresh");
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="demo">
  <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
      <select name="speed" id="speed">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1 vuxen</option>
        <option value="2">2 vuxna</option>
        <option value="3">3 vuxna</option>
        <option value="4">4 vuxna</option>
        <option value="5">5 vuxna</option>
        <option value="6">6 vuxna</option>
        <option value="7">7 vuxna</option>
        <option value="8">8 vuxna</option>
        <option value="9">9 vuxna</option>
      </select>
      <select name="test" id="test">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1 test</option>
        <option value="2">2 test</option>
        <option value="3">3 test</option>
        <option value="4">4 test</option>
        <option value="5">5 test</option>
        <option value="6">6 test</option>
        <option value="7">7 test</option>
        <option value="8">8 test</option>
        <option value="9">9 test</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's what I wanted.It works great. But one more little question.If I will have 2,3,etc  select fields an need to make variables for all of them, or any way to unify code?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how will it act if there will be more select fields.

Comment: I will make Update in post with snippet

Comment: @Balance well, it appears that my solution works only for one select, but I updated it so it could work for more.

Comment: You're fast. Yup thank's. But anyway if we have n - count of selects we need to define n-count of variables and n-count events for it. Any way to unify code?

Comment: Yep, I thought about that, but I do not have an idea right now. This is the best what I could do